# Cannot resolve a promise

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to simulate an api experience in my app since the data is stored in a json file and there won't be an http server to serve the app.

In the `api.js` file, I've this:

```
import libraries from '../store/data/data.json'

export { search }

const search = function (payload) {
  new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    resolve(payload)
  })
}
```

and from a Vuex action, I'm trying to call the api as follows:

```
import * as api from '@/api'

export const actions = {
  async SEARCH_ITEM({commit}, payload) {
    await api.search(payload)
      .then(res=>{
        console.log(res)
      })
  }
}
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined at Store.SEARCH_ITEM

Most probably I'm doing the `api.js` part wrong. Can anybody direct me in the right direction?

Comment: Are you just missing the `return` keyword in your `search` function? A promise needs to be returned.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans it's already exported. I just didn't add it in the code. It's automatically exported behind the scenes.

Comment: @Wrokar, shouldn't this `resolve()` actually return the result?

Comment: the function needs to return the promise, otherwise there is nothing to add `.then` or `.catch` to. (on that note, you're missing a `.catch(e => ...)` after your `.then(res => ...)`, which is never a good idea to forget)

Answer (score 2):

By default, a JavaScript function will return `undefined` unless you specify a return value. Your `search` function is creating a Promise, but it isn't returning that Promise. Add the `return` keyword to the function so that the Promise and the resolved value can be used by callers:

```
const search = function (payload) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    resolve(payload)
  })
}
```

Comment: Damn! you are right. Just missed that part.